# Celery Upgrade - Workers not working with RabbitMQ

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, celery, kombu

**Problem description**

- I have a working django application using Celery along with Mongo and
  RMQ (3.7.17-management-alpine)
- The application runs on kubernetes
  cluster The application works fine in general
- But when I **upgrade Celery (3.1.25) and Kombu (3.0.37) to Celery (4.1.0) and Kombu
  (4.1.0)**, I face **following issue**:

1. Celery worker pods come up but do
   not receive the tasks
2. I have verified that RMQ receives the messages
   needed to run tasks in celery workers
3. There is no error in RMQ or celery worker pod
4. In fact, celery pod mentions that it is connected
   to RMQ
5. Strangely, when I restart the RMQ pod after Celery worker pod
   comes up things become fine
6. I am able to run the new tasks in celery
   workers after I restart RMQ pod

So I guess something happened wrt Celery/Kombu/RMQ after upgrade to 4.1.0
The code works fine with older version of Celery and Kombu.

Can someone please help me wrt this?